# How do I make and use JWT role based authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-roles, asp.net-authentication

I follow the tutorial link below.

https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

I am trying to understand how it works and I want to use role-based authentication using this token. so I made another policy in the `Startup.cs` file as below.

And I tried to use it like `[Authorize(Policy = "admin")]` or `[Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]`in the controller but every time I try I get `unauthenticated` using `postman`. 
What am I missing? how to make roles-based authentication based on the tutorial?

**Startup**

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
});
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"))
);
```

**Auth Controller**

```
// POST api/auth/login
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CredentialsViewModel credentials)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);



    if (identity == null)
    {
        //return null;
        return BadRequest(Error.AddErrorToModelState("login_failure", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));
    }
    var id = identity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id").Value; 
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    IList<string> role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    var jwt = await Tokens.GenerateJwt(identity, role[0], _jwtFactory, credentials.UserName, _jwtOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });


    return new OkObjectResult(jwt);

}
```

**I tried with all method and none of them working**

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]
[HttpGet("getPolicy")]
public string GetPolicy()
{
    return "policyWorking";
}
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
[HttpGet("getAdmin")]
public string GetAdmin()
{
    return "adminWorking";
}
[Authorize ]
[HttpGet("getAuthorize")]
public string GetAuthorize()
{
    return "normal authorize Working";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly,be sure you have add json string in your `appsettings.json` otherwise you would always get `401 unauthorized`:

```
"JwtIssuerOptions": {
    "Issuer": "webApi",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

> What am I missing? how to make roles-based authentication based on the tutorial?

1.If you want to use the following way to register the service:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"))
);
```

The authorize attribute should be like below:

```
[Authorize(Policy  = "admin")]
```

2.If you want to use the following way:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

You need to remove the service from Startup.cs:

```
//services.AddAuthorization(options =>
//    options.AddPolicy("admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"))
//);
```

Then,don't forget to add claim with role in `JwtFactory.GenerateEncodedToken` like below:

```
public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedToken(string userName, ClaimsIdentity identity)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
            identity.FindFirst(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol),
            identity.FindFirst(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"admin")
    };
        //...
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkZwXaPsV4CxgkbR_a95JsHjbb6s?e=zUWTHS) is my whole project.

Comment: What is "aaa" here? Oh Gosh!!! the appsetting.json!! it was the problem!

Comment: When i make this way
 //services.AddAuthorization(options =>
//    options.AddPolicy("admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"))
//);
how can I set roles and use it? does your github have examples? Anyway Thank you so soso much

Comment: Can I ask the last thing? How can I distinguish admin and apiUser? How is it made? When login it is now automatically apiuser, then how can I make other policies and use it? do you have an example or any articles?

Comment: I have an Identity tables then I want to use aspnetRole, then if I use the second way, I can use this table do you reckon?

Comment: I think you could add if statement to judge the user role in the method `GenerateEncodedToken`.You could get the user info by username and get the role like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37546456/11398810).Then the generated token would be different.

Answer (score 0):

I've made mine using [this](https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login) tutorial.

It also works with .Net Core 3.1.

@Update

I'm using policies for that:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(Policies.RequireAny, policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, Enum.GetNames(typeof(AvailableRoles))));
    options.AddPolicy(Policies.RequireAdmin, policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            AvailableRoles.Admin.ToString()));
});
```

And in Controller

```cs
[HttpDelete("{id:int:min(1)}")]
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.RequireAdmin)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id) {
    // CODE
    return Ok();
}
```

and in creating JWT Token:

```cs
// Other claims and code...

claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, roles[0]))
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer:_appSettings.AppUrl,
    audience:_appSettings.AppUrl,
    claims: claims,
    expires: expires,
    signingCredentials: credentials
);

return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

Comment: let's say you can fetch data using token, then how do you use role? to restrict acess? can you please share how you did it?

Comment: I follow exactly, it's not working 401 unauthorized

Comment: Added more clarification