# error testing in local with Postman my ASP.NET Core 3 web API securized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1, bearer-token, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm using Azure AD to register my client web app and my web API

[image: app registrations]

[image: API ID]

[image: scope]

I grant access to my client web app

[image: grant access]

To test this I obtain an access token like this

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=webapppclientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc&scope=openid

This gets me a code

[image: code]

Now I get the access token

[image: access token]

But when I try this call to my securized controller

[image: error bad request]

In my web API I have this in appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
"Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID",
"Audience": "https://fulcrum.es/planificadorAPI"
```

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
  services
    .AddAuthentication(options=>
    {
      options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }
    ).AddJwtBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
            app
                .UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app
          .Map("/api", api =>
          {
              api.UseCors(policy =>
              {
                      policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                      policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                      policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
              })
              .UseAuthentication()
              .UseMvc();
          })
          .Run(context => context.Response.WriteAsync("FysegPlanner webAPI started"));
  }
```

In Controller

```
namespace api.Controllers
{
 [Authorize]
 [Route("proyectos")]

[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var getAllResponse = await mediator.Send(new ListAll());
    return Ok(getAllResponse);
}
```

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the GET method?

Comment: @Anuraj done. Without [Authorize] works fine

Comment: It seems you use the aad configuration to generate the jwt token? Then why you not configuring `options.TokenValidationParameters` for the jwt? I saw you just use options in your code.

Comment: @Rena because I Don't know what to do with that Parameter. When I test this from my web client app in Angular instead Postma i get Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid". So In don't know where te problem is

Comment: Here is a whole working demo about how to use jwt authentication. Refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/65228648/11398810.